# Cocoa Webkit WebPolicyDecisionListener wrong implementation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

I am developing an application on OS X with Cocoa Webkit.
I have implemented my custom WebPolicyDecisionListener but I got the fallowing error:

> Class WebPolicyDecisionListener is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit and
>   /Users/cagryInside/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacKeep-aejgqnnxruvgutahmyngzygezfse/Build/Products/Debug/MacKeep.app/Contents/MacOS/MacKeep.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
WebPolicyDecisionListener* listener = [[WebPolicyDecisionListener alloc] init];
[[self webView] setPolicyDelegate:listener];
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebPolicyDecisionListener is a *protocol*. Rather than instantiating it directly, you need to create your own class, declare conformance to WebPolicyDecisionListener, and implement the required methods.

If you're unfamiliar with using protocols, see [Programming with Objective-C: Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).